# When edit date bootstrap datepicker start date from previous years not current year

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I have an edit page that wants to edit the date using bootstraps-datepicker. It works nicely. But the problem is that when I fetch data from back-end by **value** tag in the input field the edit date starts from the year 1931 instead of 2020 (current year). I am using two script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/admin/js/formpickers.js')}}"></script>
```

input field

```
<div id="datepicker-popup" class="input-group date datepicker">
  <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" value="{{$coupon->expiry_date}}">
  <div class="input-group-addon input-group-text">
    <span class="mdi mdi-calendar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

if I remove **value** tag then it starts from 2020 but by use that I have to fetch previous given date from back-end. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `value` tag you need to give a `Date` object instead of a standard date e.g 10/12/2020

So, to convert your string value to `Date` object, you should try splitting your `$coupon->expiry_date` value to `Date` obj like this:

```
new Date(year,month,date)
```

Comment: If it helped you. Please don't forget to mark this as 'Answer'. Thanks ;)